# Find the values of U, V, C based on the given relationship...useful for upcoming puzzles

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

Given:

U, V, C are 3 distinct digits..values can vary from 1 to 9.

CU is a concatenated number

Solve for U,V, C from the following relationship:

$U^V$ X $V^U $ =   $CU $

This will give some basis to upcoming Unique Pan digital
 Fraction problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> U = 2, V = 3, C = 7: 2<sup>3</sup> × 3<sup>2</sup> = 72.
>  
>  U and V can't be too big, if U is 2 the product becomes greater than 100 even for V = 4. On the other hand, if U or V = 1, the equation becomes U = CU or V = CU, single digit on the left and two digits on the right, which is also impossible.
>  
>  If we try 2 and 3, which are not too big and not too small, we get the product 72.

Comment: ninjaed by you... :(, nvm, have an upvote!

Comment: Essentially, the number set can be constructed from U, V..This info will be helpful for the next puzzle to be posted on a unique set .

Answer (score 4):

If $U=1, 1*V=CU$ (not possible)
If $V=1, U*1=CU$ (not possible)
When $U=2$,

> $2^V*V^2<=92$
> $V<=3$
> When $V=1, 2^1*1^2=2$ (rejected)
> When $V=2, U=V$ (rejected)
> **When $V=3, 2^3*3^2=72$ (possible)**

When U=3,

> $3^V*V^3<=93$
> $V<=3$
> When $V=1, 3^1*1^3=3$ (rejected)
> When $V=2, 3^2*2^3=72$ (rejected)
> When $V=3, U=V$ (rejected)

When U=4+,

> $4^V*V^4<=94$
> $V=1$ (rejected)

Final Answer:

> When $U=2, V=3,$ and $C=7, 2^3*3^2=72$

Comment: ninja-ed by @Mariia, yet just wanna post this as a more complete explanation